# async await not working with callback node (without promise)

Tags: node.js, express

hello guys i got confused why this not working 
here is my **connection js** file

```
    function getConnection(callback) {
        initPool()
        mysql_pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }
               return callback(err, conn);
        });
     }

    function query(queryString, callback) {

        getConnection((err, connection2) => {
            if (connection2 != undefined) {
                if (err) {
                    connection2.destroy();
                return  callback(createDataResponseObject(err, null))
                }
                connection2.query(queryString, function (err, rows) {
                    connection2.destroy();
                    if (!err) {
                        return callback(createDataResponseObject(err, rows))
                    }
                    else {
                        return callback(createDataResponseObject(err, null))
                    }
                });                   
            }

        });
    }
    function createDataResponseObject(error, results) {
        if (error) {
            logger.info(error);
        }
        return {
            error: error,
            results: results === undefined ? null : results === null ? null : results
        }
    }
```

now when i acquire this connection js in my **router.js**  below is sample code

```
   var conn=require("./connection")
   router.post('/test',async function(res,req){
      var query ="select * from users"
      let x= await conn.query(result);
      console.log(x)        
   });
```

in connection js file i haven't use promise then why async  not working in router i.e it should still work because i m using callback can anyone tell me what i m missing or what i m doing wrong. when i tried it with return promise in connection.js file it working. i know async return promise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only await a promise. `conn.query` doesn't return a promise. It has no `return` statement: It returns `undefined`.

You need to [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) your database functions.

Comment: that mean it will not work which i had used in connection.js file i.e i have to return promise from function query ???

Comment: @bipin — Yes, that's what I said.

Answer (score 3):

Async/await only works with promises, it’s a syntactic sugar on top of it. I.e. you can’t use the syntax with callbacks.

Check out this link: https://javascript.info/async-await

Answer (score 1):

Async only works with promises, to get things working you have to first convert all of your function to return promises. You can use Promise.promisify() to convert all callback style function to return a promise. Once it is done you can use these function with async-await.